# Inkscape LateX rendering Fontsize

Tags: fontsize, inkscape

I'm using the LaTeX rendering extension of Inkscape to make some figures, and I want the LateX fontsize to match the one from my LateX document : 12pt.

I'm using the following input on insckape :

> \fontsize{12pt}{1mm} \selectfont $0$

However, the fontsize that appears is definitely too big. I tried to convert pt in mm and typed :

> \fontsize{4.2163mm}{1mm} \selectfont $0$

But nothing changed and the fontsize is definitely bigger than 4mm. 
How do I import the LateXFont at the right size ?

Thanks !

Comment: How do you import the image into your document?

Comment: What do you mean ? I open a new inkscape document, and I use Extension => render => LateX, and type "\fontsize{4.2163mm}{1mm} \selectfont $0$". What i obtain is a 0 of about 12mm high !

Comment: I would recommend going about this the other way around. Used the feature of Inkscape to save figures to pdf + Latex, and include that in you document. Then the font will be exactly the same (size, family ...), as inkscape then places the text in your figure in a separate tex file

Comment: Indeed, it works ! Thanks ! But it's definitely harder to place it precisely ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments